# Setting when Scrolling "bounces back" in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In `UIWebView` or any `UIScrollView` when say, you scroll to the top or bottom of a webpage and try to scroll outside it bounces back. I want to extend it by a few pixels before it bounces
back, is this possible?

Comment: See `contentInset` in the documentation for UIScrollView.

Comment: How does what you want to do differ from increasing the size of the content?

Comment: Jesse: if the content is a webpage I cannot increase it´s size

Comment: Mike: but the ScrollView in the  UIWebView is read only

Comment: try code in ViewWillAppear